# how to use GOlang methods in C++?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, go

I'm using a [GO library](https://github.com/ahmdrz/goinsta) for my project. but I am also using Qt creator so I need to bind GOlang to C++. for example there is a method `Upload` as following:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/ahmdrz/goinsta"
)

func Upload() {
    insta := goinsta.New("USERNAME", "PASSWORD")

    if err := insta.Login(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer insta.Logout()

    resp, _ := insta.UploadPhoto("PATH_TO_IMAGE", "CAPTION", insta.NewUploadID(), 87,goinsta.Filter_Lark) // default quality is 87

    fmt.Println(resp.Status)
}
```

this is in golang but I need to use it in C++. How can I call it in C++?

Comment: QT is C++, not C.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shared library in Go?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757090/shared-library-in-go)

Comment: @Olaf yes, I need to call it from c++ because I wanna build it for android.

Comment: So why use the tag for an unrelated language? C is not C++! Stop spamming tags!