# How can we execute a go binary from react native app for android or ios

Tags: react-native, go, binary

We have a go binary for different platform like mac, linux and windows and we have a react native app which is being build to run on across all platforms including mobile. On click of a button on the react app it should be executing the go binary.

Is it possible to do so. If so, how can we achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

We can do by converting the Go files to go shared libraries.

How to convert  go files to go shared libraries
[Shared library in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757090/shared-library-in-go)

Sample example showing usage of go file in the Mobile app
https://github.com/caseylmanus/go-react-native