# How to build a Go Library without a main

Tags: go

I'm a seasoned developer but new to Go. The documentation I have found is not straightforward. I'm used to Java, Scala and Python, but Go is new to me. I'm trying to create a library in Go, and I'm in the first steps of creating the project structure. When I run `go build` it tells me there are "no Go files in ...". This is a pure library and I don't want a main file. Is there a way to achieve this or is a main file required no matter what?

Finding documentation and looking at sample projects. I do have files and I have run some tests with a main file in place, but as soon as I delete the main file it's when I get a bit lost on how to build it correctly.

Comment: You can run `go build` on a library if you want to run it through the compiler to check for errors. If you are getting the "no Go files" error, that probably means you are running the command in the wrong directory.

Comment: More specifically, your question was closed for "not reproducible". In order to reproduce the error you are getting, we would probably need to know: 1. The complete error message. 2. Your project directory structure and files. 3. The content of the files. 4. The exact command you are running and where you are running it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends a bit on what you mean by "library". If you mean a pre-compiled binary object, like a `.a` or `.so` library in C, Go doesn't really have anything like that. Dependent packages are downloaded as source and then compiled into your binary.

If you mean, "a module I can import and use in other projects"...Have you looked to see how other modules are structured? Using e.g. the [`yaml`](https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml) module as an example, we see:

- There is no `main.go`
- If you clone it and run `go mod tidy; go build` the `go build` command will run without errors.

So for example I can create a module `mymodule-dep` with this structure:

```
.
├── functions.go
└── go.mod
```

Where `go.mod` has:

```
module github.com/larsks/mymodule-dep

go 1.20
```

And `functions.go` has:

```
package mymodule_dep

import "strings"

func Replace(s string) string {
    return strings.Replace(s, "Hello", "Goodbye", -1)
}
```

---

I can **use** that module by importing into another project, like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    dep "github.com/larsks/mymodule-dep"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(dep.Replace("Hello, world!"))
}
```

This assumes that there exists a repository https://github.com/larsks/mymodule-dep (which does exist right now).

If I build the above code, running it produces:

```
Goodbye, world!
```

Comment: Thank you. That was an educational example

Comment: It is possible to create a shared library (.so) from Go code, referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1757090/4366445)

Answer (score 1):

Usually you do not need to build your GO libraries.

You create library as GO files, test it and publish sources to GitHub. Published code has versions in Git (typically GitHub) and client can pick what version of library to use.

The client application that uses that library has a `main.go` file, and that is where you run `go build` command.

Go does not have an intermediate format like Java or .NET and also do not use libraries in binary executable format. Instead, GO uses dependencies in the form of GO code. That is similar to Node and Python, except, Go compiles final code and do not interpret it.

Comment: Technically Go does use a compiled object file format for libraries, it’s just not distributed as part of the library. The object files are what are linked together to create the final binary.